# Creating Symbian application using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, symbian

Does tooling exist for Visual Studio that makes it possible to create a Symbian mobile application using .NET?

Answer (score 3):

> In the past, Visual Basic, VB.NET, and C# development for Symbian were possible through AppForge Crossfire, a plugin for Microsoft Visual Studio. On 13 March 2007 AppForge ceased operations; Oracle purchased the intellectual property, but announced that they did not plan to sell or provide support for former AppForge products. Net60, a .NET compact framework for Symbian, which is developed by redFIVElabs

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian#Other_languages

Answer (score 3):

I guess RedFiveLabs (the maker of .NET for Symbian) is out of business. Except for links to their website, I can't find anything anymore from them. Their website is unreachable ( http://www.redfivelabs.com ) Their product is/was called Net60.

Silverlight is available for the S60 5th gen devices: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/devices/symbian/

Symbian itself is also almost dead,  their Symbian^3 isn't good enough, and I guess Nokia put their bets on MeeGo (although I read somewhere that even Windows Phone 7 was an option).

This makes the development of anything for Symbian not really worthwhile, also since the current user base doesn't interact with the OVI appstore like users of other phone OS's.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only .NET platform is Windows.

There is also Mono for linu, but I am almost sure, that you can't code in c# for symbian.

Comment: .NET for iPhone (monotouch), Linux (web + desktop), and perhaps Mono on the PS3 (supposedly under development)

Answer (score 0):

There's an article on that here: http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/net-compact-framework-on-symbian.aspx

It contains a link to an interesting article on porting the .NET Compact Framework to Symbian phones. http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2006_04/article4/

That article stated:

> Our analysis shows that the specifics
>   of the Symbian OS and the resource
>   constraints of today’s smartphones
>   make porting difficult but not
>   impossible.

In other words, it's POSSIBLE but probably not worth your effort.